# C# dictionary pattern, which is best?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Which of these patterns should be preferred over the other and why?

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> data in
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { 
        {"HtmlAttributes", this.HtmlAttributes},
        {"Content", this.Content}
    }) 
{
     foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data.Value)
     {
         // do something
     }
}
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
data.Add("HtmlAttributes", this.HtmlAttributes);
data.Add("Content", this.Content);

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary<string, string>> entry in data) 
{
    // Do something
}           

data.Clear(); // not sure if this is needed either
data = null;  // gc object
```

Please don't answer with "use var", as I don't like using it.

**Re: `var` (2 years later):** I must add something to make this right. In retrospect, reading Eric Lipert's blog post about when and why to use `var` makes total sense. IF used appropriately, meaning not all the time, it makes perfect sense and it shortens the amount code one needs to read. On the matter of what initialization to use, well the object initializer is fine, but splitting up initialization from the `foreach` or other processing makes the code more readable.

Comment: You don't like using it? Seriously? When the alternative is that convoluted mess?

Comment: Seriously! I dislike var as much as Dim.

Comment: var is a perfectly valid technique... especially in a situation like what you've outlined.

Comment: It's not even clear what you're trying to achieve here. Why are these mutually exclusive options? It depends what "Do something" needs to do. For example, you might instead map a string to a func that returns the items related to that string.

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive, they are equivalent. Again, this is about the pattern of iterating over a dictionary of dictionaries, and how you instantiate things. I don't think you understand what I am talking about.

Comment: Folks, OP did say he doesn't want to use var so just answer the question, (or not). Use of `var` is entirely [subjective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633474/c-do-you-use-var), has been done to death on SO so there's no point squabbling about it in the comments.

Comment: @Kev Subjectivity is overrated, especially when used instead of arguments in discussions. (1) `var` has objective advantages here, (2) judging from usual discussions, supporters of `var` among professional programmers seem to outweigh skeptics by far (and your link supports this), (3) Eric Lippert has argued in favour of it, (4) the OP seems to operate from false premises.

Comment: In most cases, there is no need to set a local variable to `null` just so that it can be GCed. The compiler is smart enough to figure that out by itself. Also, don't forget, that setting a variable to `null` doesn't imply that the object is immediatelly GCed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer something in between your two versions: split creation and iteration, but use collection initializer.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dicts =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { 
    {"HtmlAttributes", this.HtmlAttributes},
    {"Content", this.Content}
});

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> data in dicts)
{
     foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data.Value)
     {
         // do something
     }
}
```

or equivalently (really, from the point of view of both the compiler and IDE, the following is exactly the same):

```
var dicts = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> { 
    {"HtmlAttributes", this.HtmlAttributes},
    {"Content", this.Content}
});

foreach(var data in dicts)
{
     foreach(var entry in data.Value)
     {
         // do something
     }
}
```

Also, if you're using `Dictionary` just as a list of pairs, you could use either `List<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` or (on .Net 4) `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the comments by Kent Boogaart and quakkels are right. var makes sense here. If I had to choose one of your two I'd say the 2nd is better as it's slightly easier to read.

Comment: Fine, the point of this question is not about using var or not. Sure, var is valid and so is Dim, I don't like using it.

Comment: @Roland Your insistence to compare it to `Dim` suggests that you don’t know what `var` actually is, and that you are ascribing semantics to it (namely, weak typing) which it doesn’t have.

Comment: @Konrad. Could you please explain the difference between Dim and var? Thanks!

Comment: Probably, I don't understand Dim, since the first and only time I used it was in 2000, in vb 6, and I hated it. My dislike of implicit typing is that it makes code extremely difficult without visual studio and intellisense. For instance, think of this: foreach(var x in obj1.Parent.Properties), to undrestand what the type of the properties, you need to have access to that code. var makes C# look a bit more like dynamic languages, where you still have that problem. But dynamic language projects are most often OSS, C# aren't.

Comment: @Squid These two don’t really compare. There is no equivalent of `Dim` in C# – it’s merely used to syntactically denote the start of a variable declaration. However, many people think that `Dim` implies weak typing (because its original use was not in declaring a *typed* variable, but rather to dimension an array in a language with weak typing).

Comment: @Roland Comments are no fit place for a discussion. However, I urge you to consider [Eric Lippert’s take on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx) before dismissing `var` (and implicit typing). Eric Lippert is one of the main architects of C# and he offers good insight why knowing the exact type of a variable is overrated. Also, when do you ever read C# code without Visual Studio? Is this really a situation that you want to optimise your code for?

Comment: @Konrad, you're right. sorry, newbee to this stack forum. apologies for sidetracking this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second version is more readable. Given that you don't like to use `var`, that seems even more important as your first version kind of gives me a headache.

I also think that it's a little convoluted to mix the code that creates a collection with the code that loops through it.

So, for me, it's a matter of readability and I prefer the second version. But in the end, either one works.